# How to install .NET 4.5 silently on Windows Server 2008 R2 using powershell Script.?

Tags: .net, powershell

I have tried installing **.NET** using **PowerShell 2.0** by the following command:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\dotNetFx45_Full_setup 
                   EULA_ACCEPT=YES REMOVE_PREVIOUS=YES /v /qn
```

It will not make the license agreement ticked automatically..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c63838b5-a6d9-496d-ac88-2e32c1ae131f/silent-install-of-net-45-in-powershell-issue?forum=winserverpowershell) link

Also use [this](https://exchangemaster.wordpress.com/2016/03/16/quick-method-to-determine-installed-version-of-net-framework/)

Hope your helps

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: Thanks..I found Another command that solved my issue . 
".\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe  /q " did the job for me.